# Read command in shell scripting

Tags: shell

I have this script:

```
    echo -e ">> Please, insert edition folder name: ";
    read editionfolder;
    RSeditionfolder="$editionfolder";    
    sh -c $POSTGRESbin'psql -U '$POSTGRESuser' -h localhost -d '$POSTGRESdb' -c "select count(*) from d3_folders where folder_name = '\'$RSeditionfolder\'';"' > $queryFolder$tmpFile
```

For example, if I insert in editionfolder var: CD_199 FOTOS I receive an error:

```
FOTOS';": -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
FOTOS';": -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

$queryFolder has "query/" value and $tmpFile has "tmpfile"

But I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

The result of this query is:

```
 count 
-------
     0
(1 row)
```

I only want the number 0, in this case. I'm triying to put the result in a file and the next step is use sed in this file, I you know other way I would be very grateful to know it.

Thanks !!

Comment: is POSTGRESbin a single name of a variable or it's a concatenation of ${POSTGRES}bin ?

Comment: Also, I would swap escaping here: `'\'$RSeditionfolder\''` to `\''$RSeditionfolder'\'`

Comment: Does something like `sh -c "${POSTGRESbin}psql -U $POSTGRESuser -h localhost -d $POSTGRESdb -c \"select count(*) from d3_folders where folder_name = '$RSeditionfolder';\"" > ${queryFolder}${tmpFile}` do what you need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The given command is a little messy, I would write that like

```
sh -c "${POSTGRESbin}psql -U $POSTGRESuser -h localhost -d $POSTGRESdb -c \"select count(*) from d3_folders where folder_name = '$RSeditionfolder';\"" > ${queryFolder}${tmpFile}
```

First of all, I would get rid of all those single quotes using $-variables inside the double quotes. Second, it would be good to clarify clause ’$queryFolder$tmpFile’ using explicit variable name borders, `${queryFolder}${tmpFile}`. But in general the script is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Leave out all those single quotes from `sh -c ...` and quote the whole command with double quotes:

```
sh -c "$POSTGRESbin/psql -U $POSTGRESus -h ..."
```

The double quotes ensure, that there is just one argument and simultaneously allow substitution of shell variables.